# AWS 'eb deploy' always zip all files

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i'm new using git with eb cli, for deploy my code to aws elastic beanstalk. I though the most vantage thing on eb cli was deploy specific files (from commit), but every time i commit some files and deploy my application, eb cli zip all project and this is too much for upload all the time.
Please help me, i read almost everything about it on aws documentation and there's nothign about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the EB CLI does not support incremental uploads of your application. Every time you use `eb deploy` it will zip up your entire project and upload it as a new Application Version.

EDIT:

As of version 3.8.0 EB CLI now supports AWS CodeCommit.

You can setup your current git repository to work with code commit with the following commands.

```
$ eb codesource codecommit
```

Which will take you through an interactive setup to use AWS CodeCommit. It is supported with the EB CLI to deploy incremental git commits to the CodeCommit repository and then deploy to your Elastic Beanstalk environment from there.

For more information check out the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-codecommit.html).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to further customize your deployment and not just deploy your current branch; I believe you're going to have to manually specify an artifact yourself and build the zip yourself before calling `eb deploy`.

In your `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`:

```
deploy:
  artifact: some-custom-zip.zip
```

The artifact should exist in the same directory as the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory.
And you could create a bash script to generate your own custom zip file for uploading use before calling eb deploy or use a Makefile.

Example Makefile:

```
some-custom-zip.zip: something.py another.py
    zip $@ something.py another.py

deploy: some-custom-zip.zip
    eb deploy

.PHONY: deploy
```

Comment: Here i add the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact) related to this answer.